# Que significa bind() (socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) en este código

Tags: python

```
import socket 


ip='0.0.0.0'
port=8888
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    server.bind((ip,port))

    server.listen(5)

    print "Listning on %s %s" %(ip,port)

    (obj,cliente)=server.accept()

    print "Conexion recived from %s" %cliente[0]

    while True:

        msg=obj.recv(1024)
        print msg

    server.close()    
except Exception as erro:
    print erro
    server.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ni idea de *python*, pero lo que indicas son funciones POSIX de manejo de *sockets* para el trabajo con conexiones de red:

- `server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)`

Función para crear un *socket*, un *conector* para poder realizar conexiones en red.

`socket.AF_INET` es el *domino* del conector. En este caso, un conector IPv4.

`socket.SOCK_STREAM` *tipo* del conector, dependiente del parámetro anterior (no todos los *dominios* soportan los mismos *tipos*). En este caso, un *conector* de tipo `STREAM`: usando el protocolo *TCP*, que proporciona ciertas garantías de seguridad: los paquetes llegan en orden, descartando los repetidos y/o dañados.

- `server.bind((ip,port))`

Asocia el conector con la dirección IP y el *puerto* indicados. Comprueba que están disponibles, y los *reserva* para nosotros.

- `server.listen(5)`

Pone el conector en *modo escucha*. A partir de este momento, se aceptan peticiones de conexión en el mismo.

El número `5` indica la capacidad de la *cola de conexiones pendientes*. Si la cola está llena y hay mas peticiones de conexión, estas se descartan.